# Linq group string array by count and sort

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<string> _words` like

```
"Car", "Car", "Car", "Bird", "Sky", "Sky"
```

I want to sort it by each word count descending so the final `List<string>` would be

```
"Car",
"Sky",
"Bird
```

how do I do this in LINQ? I don't really need the count for each word

in SQL this would be:

```
select word, count(1) as count1
from word
group by word
order by count1 desc, word
```

### Answer

Another variant:

```
    var _output = from p in _words
                  group p by p into g
                  orderby g.Count() descending, g.Key ascending 
                  select g.Key;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to use a combination of `GroupBy` and `OrderByDescending`:

```
string[] words = {"Car", "Car", "Car", "Bird", "Sky", "Sky"};
var output = words
    .GroupBy(word => word)
    .OrderByDescending(group => group.Count())   
    .Select(group => group.Key);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `GroupBy()` then `OrderByDescending()` to order by number of occurrence starting from the most frequent :

```
var result = _words.GroupBy(x => x)
                   .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
                   .Select(x => x.Key)
                   .ToList();
```