# finding amount of same texts

Tags: c#, string

hello I am making a survival game but I don't know how to make if there is some same text in a string it deletes it and then makes it to

`<amount><item.title>`

here is the code

```cs
string[] needs = new string[items.Length];
string text = "";

for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
{
     text += items[i].title + ",";
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the input and desired output?

Comment: thats the crafting system and it tells the needed items

Comment: [Linq group string array by count and sort](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25717288/205233)

Comment: If they only have ONE of a certain item, should it be `<1><item.title>` or just `item.title`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to create a string without duplicates based on your list of items, you can first create another list of items that doesn't contain duplicates. You will need LINQ for this.

```
var distinctItemGroups = items.GroupBy(item => item.Title);
```

I would also recommend using a [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-6.0) for the text. You can then do something like this:

```
var displayText = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var group in distinctItemGroups)
{
   displayText.Append(group.First().Title + ", ");
}
```

To actually display the text from the StringBuilder just call ToString() on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:
Create a class for count items

```
public class MyResultModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Count}{Title}";
    }
}
```

And fill the items with

```
IEnumerable<MyResultModel> myModels = items.GroupBy(x => x)
                .Select(x => new MyResultModel() { Count = x.Count(), Title = x.Key });
```

Then you can generate a string:

```
string result = string.Join(",", myModels.Select(x=> x.ToString()));
```